# Which parser generator to teach my students?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

I am teaching (with others) a relatively introductory course in computer science for IT professionals without a background in CS. Since I developed the course materials on automata and grammars, I am also responsible for teaching about compilers and compiler construction.

Years ago, when I studied compilation in college, all our examples came from Lex and Yacc. Are these still in widespread use? Is there something that is more commonly used for Java? The students are proficient in C and Java but have never used parser generators.

Any tips on what to teach would be appreciated

Comment: This would be on-topic at http://cseducators.stackexchange.com (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter through here https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) is widely used, well documented, and free. It is supported by Ant, and can target Java among many other languages.

Comment: That's right. If they already know java, antlr is the way to go.

Answer (score 14):

I don't use lexer and parser generators. They're simple enough to generate by hand, and are the easiest parts of a compiler to write. Besides, when you build them by hand, you can make them really fast.

Comment: You apparently have never written complicated parser/lexers... you really don't want to maintain those by hand if they get complicated.

Comment: Yes, I've done parsers and lexers by hand that do arbitrary lookahead and backtracking, and even one for C++! (The C++ is a bit harder because of its interactions with the preprocessor, tokens that exist or not based on compiler switches, etc.)

Comment: More Necromancy...  I love the arrogance of youth.  Jorn, if you still have any attention span left...  www.digitalmars.com

Comment: @Jorn Do you know who you are addressing? lol

Comment: I don't, but I stand by my comment. Sorry if I have offended anyone.

Answer (score 10):

It's a pity your students aren't well-versed in C++.  Once I came across the [Spirit](http://spirit.sourceforge.net/) library with its concept of a rich, EBNF-style DSL, I've left Antlr, Lex and Yacc behind!  It's *much* more flexible having the grammar described alongside the code.

Brilliant library, though with an admittedly non-trivial learning curve.

However, without C++, [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) is probably your best bet.

Comment: I even used spirit to parse command line arguments ... :)

Comment: Don't like the program_options library, eh? :)

Comment: in our university (i'm still studying), we use Boost::Spririt as basis for teaching both parsing and advanced C++.
It works really well for those who are motivated to learn, but of course, seems far too indepth for cruisy students

Answer (score 5):

Lex and Yacc are still in use. One of the newest languages around, F#, has it's own versions (fslex, fsyacc -- see [here](http://strangelights.com/blog/archive/2006/05/11/1302.aspx) for an example.) So I think teaching them is still relevant.

Answer (score 5):

Yacc and all the other LALR(1) parsers date from an era when machine resources were scarce and it was necessary to spend a lot of time engineering the grammar so that you could run a parser at all on a PDP-11 with 64K of RAM.  Today it does not make sense to teach a tool like yacc with a terrible human interface and a very limited set of grammars it can use.

I would recommend either one of the PEG-based parsers, such as Rats!, or the GLR parser [Elkhound](http://www.scottmcpeak.com/elkhound/) developed by George Necula and Scott McPeak (thanks quark).  Sorry I can't recommend a specific tool for Java, but Rats! is good for C.

ANTLR is OK but is too complex for my taste.

Comment: Open source GLR parser: Elkhound.  http://www.scottmcpeak.com/elkhound.  It's even been used to generate a C++ parser.

Answer (score 3):

PEG parser systems like [RATS](http://cs.nyu.edu/rgrimm/xtc/rats.html) are simpler than the lex/yacc combo. This may or may not be a plus for your class: is your goal to teach about regular expressions and finite automata, and LR grammars and pushdown automata, etc.? Or do you want the simplest practical compiler frontend tools?

(Since I don't program in Java these days I haven't tried RATS in particular.)

Answer (score 2):

Javacc it's very easy.
In the same file you have the grammar and the token list.

https://javacc.dev.java.net/

Answer (score 1):

I remember using CUP and liking it.  Take a look at the [CUP Parser Generator for Java](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/java/CUP/).

CUP is maintained at the Technical University of Munich.  I believe it's primary purpose is to teach students.

It also has a free licensing model.

> ...Permission to use, copy, modify, and
>   distribute this software and its
>   documentation for any purpose and
>   without fee is hereby granted,
>   provided that the above copyright
>   notice appear in all copies and that
>   both the copyright notice and this
>   permission notice and warranty
>   disclaimer appear in supporting
>   documentation...

Comment: If you teach CS, you may be interested in the new [CS Educator's Stack Exchange](http://cseducators.stackexchange.com) (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter [through here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators))

Answer (score 1):

You could skip the generator part and have a look at Scalas parser combinators.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to work with Java, JavaCC or ANTLR should suffice. This latter one also supports C and Python. But if you plan to work with C++, maybe you should take a look at Boost::Spirit.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it yet, but I found [jparsec](http://jparsec.codehaus.org) a few days ago. It is no parser generator, instead the parser is build in java by combinators in an EBNF style.

Answer (score 1):

I like the [GOLD Parsing System](http://www.devincook.com/) very much, because it basically generates the tables needed and you then only have to use a (generic) implementation of a processor which uses the table information to process the tokens. This engine (as it is called) is quite easy to write and is basically a pure implementation using the LALR and DFA tables to process the input, and writing such an implementation may be a good exercise to teach those.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently taking a compilers course which uses Lex and Yacc. I don't really know about any other types out there, but the theory we're learning seems to map pretty well to these tools.

Answer (score 0):

I remember using Bison in one of my compilers classes.  We also used flex and YACC.

Answer (score 0):

OCaml has a fantastic set of parser generators. [Here](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/ocaml/benefits/parsing.html) are some simple examples.

JavaCC is also quite good.

I would strongly recommend avoiding C (and C++) for this purpose because they are extraordinary painful in this context.